# Echo a specific value on a very nested array

Tags: php, arrays, nested

I have a function that generate an array (I did not made that function, comes from an API) and then saves it to a variable($customerList). I need to display just one value of an entire nested array; this array contains all this code (shown with print_r($customerList);) :

```
Array
(
[0] => Customer Object
    (
        [status:protected] => 
        [creation_date:protected] => 2016-01-14T12:07:07-06:00
        [balance:protected] => 
        [clabe:protected] => 321654qweasd
        [derivedResources:protected] => Array
            (
                [cards] => 123123123123
                //a lot of code
```

How can I display just the value on "[cards]" using echo?

I have tried

```
//the for loop {
echo $customerList['0']['derivedResources:protected']['cards'];
```

And

```
//the for loop {
echo $customerList['0']['derivedResources']['cards'];
```

But it just display nothing. I haven't seen an array like this, so maybe is just a newbie mistake.

I think that "protected" thing has something to do with; but if I can display it, I can read/access it, right?

If any of you need the entire array (it's very long) I can put it here.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `echo $customerList[0]['derivedResources']['cards'];`

Comment: I tried, but all the php after that line doesn't work. It just stop there.

Comment: Sorry, my bad: `echo $customerList[0]->derivedResources->cards;`

Comment: Hmm now it works the code, but it still doesn't display the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I haven't seen an array like this

It is an array of objects. Learn something about OOP.

This should work:

```
echo $customerList[0]->derivedResources['cards'];
```

Comment: Tried. Just like other ways that I did it, the code after that line doesn't work.

Comment: Show us what is displayed after `var_dump($customerList)`, `var_dump($customerList[0])` and `var_dump($customerList[0]->derivedResources)`.

Comment: I made a little mistake, I'm looking for: "name" in "serializableData", but it's the same (0->serializableData->name).Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/UzERshBZ. You can Ctrl+F to find ["name"] or [name] because there's a lot of code =D

Comment: Since your last answer I have not changed the code. I just Ctrl+Shift+R to reload, and now it works, I did it just like you type it on the answer. I'm not sure if it was that I had the API session closed (I still had access to the values, so I dont think this was the problem), or jsut the cheap server where I have temporally mounted the project, or something else. Anyway, this works perfectly even on deeper levels of the array. Thank you so much =D

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `print_r`:

```
Array
(
[0] => Customer Object
    (
        [status:protected] => 
        [creation_date:protected] => 2016-01-14T12:07:07-06:00
        [balance:protected] => 
        [clabe:protected] => 321654qweasd
        [derivedResources:protected] => Array
            (
                [cards] => 123123123123
                //a lot of code
```

We can simulate:

```
<?php

$CustomerObject = new \stdClass;
$derivedResources = new \stdClass();
$CustomerObject->derivedResources = ["cards" => 123123123123];

$customerList = [$CustomerObject];

// print_r($customerList);

echo $customerList[0]->derivedResources['cards'];
```

Which, uncommenting the `print_r` results in:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [derivedResources] => Array
            (
                [cards] => 123123123123
            )
    )
)
123123123123
```

Comment: This works perfectly; seems like there was a trouble with my bad server or the API session. Thank you a lot.

Comment: At least you found the issue ! (;